# How to reset the value of page parameter of tableParams to 1 using ng-Table of angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ng-Table of AngularJS for searching, sorting and pagination in my application. After searching I want to reset the value of page parameter of `tableParams` to 1. How can I achieve the same?

```
$scope.$watch("filter.$", function() {
  $scope.tableParams.reload();
  $scope.caseWOTableParams.reload();
});


$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({  
    page: 1  , // show first page
    count: 10, // count per page
    sorting: {
      name: "desc"
    } //Initial sorting.
    //filter: $scope.filter //filter
}, {
  total: $scope.completedQueries.length, // length of data
  getData: function($defer, params) {
    var filteredData = $filter('filter')(newWorkOrder, $scope.filter);
  }
  var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
    $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) : filteredData;
  //orderedData = $filter('filter')(orderedData, params.filter());
  params.total(orderedData.length);
  $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
  //filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions;
},
$scope: $scope
}
);
```

Comment: @David thanks a lot...it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just need to pass parameter as mentioned below:

```
$scope.$watch("filter.$", function()
{
    $scope.tableParams.reload();
    $scope.caseWOTableParams.reload(); 
    $scope.tableParams.page(1);//reset page to 1 after filter.
});
```